# fire a event after finish write in angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I would like fire a search after my user finish write (without a enter) in angularjs.

My html (simplified):

```
<div ng-class="input-append" ng-controller="searchControl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="ajaxSearch" ng-change="search();">
</div>
```

My AngularJs (simplified):

```
$scope.searchControl = function() {                
  $scope.search = function(){
    $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '<?php echo base_url('system/ajax_search/') ?>',
          'data: search=' + $scope.ajaxSearch,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
       }).success(function(data) {
          $scope.result = data;
       });
}
```

The original code is extensive, so i simplified.
In my code, i post data always my user change the search. 
I would like post data seconds after my user stop to write.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily achieved with a directive:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('keyboardPoster', function($parse, $timeout){
  var DELAY_TIME_BEFORE_POSTING = 3000;
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    var element = angular.element(elem)[0];
    var currentTimeout = null;

    element.onkeypress = function() {
      var model = $parse(attrs.postFunction);
      var poster = model(scope);
      if(currentTimeout) {
        $timeout.cancel(currentTimeout)
      }
      currentTimeout = $timeout(function(){
        poster();
      }, DELAY_TIME_BEFORE_POSTING)
    }
  }
})
.controller('testController', function($scope){
  $scope.search = function() {
    console.log("Executing query...");
  }
})
```

And it can be used like this...

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='testController'>
  <input type="text" keyboard-poster post-function="search">
</div>
```

Use `$timeout` and cancel each time user types; if the timeout runs, executes the scoped function given as an attr. You can modify the delay time to whatever fits better your user experience (I wouldn't drop it below `1000` though).

Comment: just a little update - you have to use `element.onkeydown` instead of `element.onkeypress` if you want to handle backspace (obviously it is necessary almost always)